# How i can resize Images with imagescale in PHP

Tags: php, image

i tried to **resize an image** with **following method:**

**code**

```
$thumbimg = $img->resizeImage($thumb, 200, 200);

public function resizeImage($imagePath,$new_width,$new_height) {

            $fileName = pathinfo($imagePath,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $ext = pathinfo($imagePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $fullPath = pathinfo($imagePath,PATHINFO_DIRNAME)."/".$fileName.'.'.$ext;
            if (file_exists($fullPath)) {
                return $fullPath;
            }
            $image = $this->openImage($imagePath);
            if ($image == false) {
                return null;
            }
            $width = imagesx($image);
            $height = imagesy($image);
            $imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

            if ($imageResized == false) {
                return null;
            }
            $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width , $height);

            $imageResized = imagescale($image,$new_width,$new_height);
            touch($fullPath);
            $write = imagepng($imageResized,$fullPath);
            if (!$write) {
                imagedestroy($imageResized);    
                return null;
            }
            imagedestroy($imageResized);
            return $fullPath;
        }
```

Actual its saves my images in the original width and height. But why? Whats wrong?

Comment: Have you checked your logs for error messages?

Comment: We don't even know `$this->openImage()`. And it's off-topic (*why isn't code working*).

Comment: yes, no errors @Difster

Comment: @digijay ok thx. then i'll try to find the solution in php forum.

Comment: Rather add code to your question by using the edit button. And most probably you don't get errors because they are suppressed by `@`, remove them.

Comment: Please note that file systems can be case sensitive, so using `strtolower()` might not be the best idea. You could actually end up changing a correct path to a non-existing one.

Answer (score 0):

If `$imagePath` refers to an existing image, then `$fullPath` will refer to that same file. So either the file exists, in which case it is returned, or the file does not exist, in which case you can't open the image and `null` is returned. Either way, the image resize code is not used.